# How to fix code_to_names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function code_to_names which takes an int crime code and returns the a list of string where each of the string contains the code extension and full name of the crime.

Right now, the it is outputting the entire list instead of a specific one. How do I fix that?

```
import csv

def code_to_names(code):
    names = []
    with open('offense_codes.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        next(reader)  # skip the first row
        for row in reader:
            names.append(line)
    return names
```

> code_to_names(2399)
>   ['0: Theft - other', '1: Bicycle theft', '2: Theft of fuel by driving off without paying', '3: Theft of cable services', '4: Theft of construction equipment', '5: Theft of a trailer'] 
>   code_to_names(5707)
>   ['0: Criminal trespassing']

Answer (score 1):

To open that file you can either provide full path to the file eg. `C:\Users\Desktop\offense_codes.csv`  or using `os` module change your current working directory to Desktop eg.
 `os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Desktop')`

To start one of those functions you need to call one of them like: `code_to_names()`

I recommend you read the "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" by Al Sweigert. It's perfect for beginners and completely free https://automatetheboringstuff.com/